# qplot stack bar chart

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've been trying to create a bar chart for a while now, but I need help:

```
name    <- c('t1','t2')
reading <- c('yyyggrggryyy','grgrgrrryyyy')
df <- data.frame(name, reading)
```

The reading value can only be 'y', 'g' or 'r' and the length of the string is always 12.
I tried to 'convert' the reading into a stacked bar chart for each name like this:

t1 stacked bar:

```
Color  Height
------ ------
yellow 3
green  2
red    1
green  2
red    1
yellow 3
```

Thanks

Comment: How did you try to do the conversion, exactly? What didn't work?

Answer (score 7):

```
> df <- data.frame(name=rep(name, each=12), 
                   reading=unlist(sapply(reading, strsplit, split="")))
> df
               name reading
yyyggrggryyy1    t1       y
yyyggrggryyy2    t1       y
yyyggrggryyy3    t1       y
yyyggrggryyy4    t1       g
snipped
grgrgrrryyyy4    t2       r
grgrgrrryyyy5    t2       g
grgrgrrryyyy6    t2       r
grgrgrrryyyy7    t2       r
grgrgrrryyyy8    t2       r
grgrgrrryyyy9    t2       y
grgrgrrryyyy10   t2       y
grgrgrrryyyy11   t2       y
grgrgrrryyyy12   t2       y

 qplot(reading,  data=df, geom="bar")+facet_grid(~name)
```

[image]

If you want a stacked barplot, then you need to pass an x argument that is the same for the grouping variable you want stacked:

```
qplot(x=name,  data=df)+facet_grid(~name)+geom_bar(aes(fill = reading))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Tried it and is working nice... but I cannot find a way yet to make t1 a single bar, stacked with 3 units of yellow and on top, 2 of green, 1 red, 2 green, 1 red and 3 yellow. Do you think qplot has the capability of doing that?

Comment: I put an example up that used faceting but you could drop the facet_grid command and still get a stacked barplot : `qplot(x=name,  data=df, geom="bar", fill=reading)`

Comment: Worked nice and with a couple of minor modifications I could create a nice looking graph! I'm still testing geom_bar, which seems that always group the readings, stack them and create the graph. Can geom_bar repeat colors like this http://tinyurl.com/n8zjt9u ?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
m<-strsplit(as.character(df$reading),"") # split the strings 
data1<-as.data.frame(table(m[[1]])) # create dataframe for first element of reading
data2<-as.data.frame(table(m[[2]])) # create dataframe for second element of reading
t<-rep(c("t1","t2"),c(dim(data1)[1],dim(data2)[1])) 
t<-as.data.frame(t) # create dataframe of t which gives t1 and t2
mydata<-cbind(rbind(data1,data2),t)  #final data for plot
mydata$reading<-mydata$Var1
qplot(reading, data=mydata, geom="bar",weight=Freq)+facet_grid(~t)
```

[image]